# Why clustering in a linear scale using correlation based distance gives better results than clustering in a log2 scale?(PAM clustering)

Tags: correlation, clustering, normalization, distance, lognormal-distribution

I have questions regarding cluster analysis.
I am trying to cluster data made up of proteins. (23 columns and 1800 rows)
I have the data in a log2 scale, some variables range between 2-10 and others between -1 and 2 despite that all variables have the same unit (**NPX**). Also, **all variables are scaled and normally distributed.** The silhouette width of my data on this scale is around 0.15. However, if I convert my data into the linear scale(2^the data) and run cluster analysis, the silhouette width increases up to 0.5!!. **My questions are:**

1)Does that make sense? Because despite that all variables in the same unit, the range in the linear scale vary a lot(some variables 400-10 or 1000-5000, and others 1-10)  which means that some variables will have greater weight, right?

2)shall I run cluster analysis using the data in log2 scale or linear scale?

3. If I use correlation-based distance instead of manhattan or euclidean distance, the silhouette width gets larger which is desirable to me. However, is that a viable or correct method? because my data is made up of proteins and not gene expression as I read that correlation-based distance is usually used for gene expression and not proteomics.
4. Do I need to scale the data or standardize it if my data is actually normalized?(based on the histograms of the variables)

I apologize if some of this isn't very clear. Please let me know, I will clarify specific details. Thank you very much!

Code used

```
#clustering log2 scale data
dist.cor.pearson.log2<-get_dist(cluster.data,method="pearson")

x2.log2<-fviz_silhouette(pam(dist.cor.pearson.log2,2,diss = T))
x3.log2<-fviz_silhouette(pam(dist.cor.pearson.log2,3,diss = T))
grid.arrange(x2.log2,x3.log2)

#clustering linear data
cluster.data.linear<-(2^cluster.data)

dist.cor.pearson<-get_dist(cluster.data.linear,method="pearson")
x2.linear<-fviz_silhouette(pam(dist.cor.pearson,2,diss = T))
x3.linear<-fviz_silhouette(pam(dist.cor.pearsonn,3,diss = T))
grid.arrange(x3.linear,x2.linear)
```

This is clustering in a log2 scale(sil width 0.19-0.12) using pearson correlation as distance metric.
[image]

This is clustering in a linear scale(sil width +0.5) using pearson correlation as distance metric.

[image]